# How would I call image from js file on wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have *peel.js* file it has located in root directory (e.g. `http://mydomain.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/anbo/peel.js`).

I have called two image from *peel.js* file, but images not called otherwise not working.

My code:

```
smartredfox.small_image = 'small.jpg';
smartredfox.big_image = 'large.jpg';

smartredfox.small_path = 'small.swf';
smartredfox.big_path = 'large.swf';
```

I need help for call the image, otherwise need code for check whether images working or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is just assigning strings, it does not "call" any image.

To actually load the image and show it, have such code:

```
smartredfox.small_image = 'small.jpg';
$("<img />").attr("src", smartredfox.small_image).appendTo("body");
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/k8Lhf/).